# My PHP code is interfering on my footer

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a ecommerce store, i think my php code is working well, i can see all the information in my page, but the code is interfering on my footer, here the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcBU1.png

My php home code:

http://pastebin.com/MLCWKUyy

My php products code:

```
<?php include('cms/conectar.php');
?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<style>
.prodColuna { text-align:center; width:300px; float:left; height:100%  }
</style>


<?php
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `livros-desporto` ");

 if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
    $consulta = mysql_query("
        SELECT * FROM `livros-desporto` where name like '%".$_POST['buscar']."%'
    ");
}

while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    $id = $linha['ID'];
    $modelo = $linha['Model'];
    $nome = $linha['Name'];
    $categoria = $linha['Category'];
    $imagem = $linha['Image'];
    $manufactura = $linha['Manufacturer'];
    $preco = $linha['Price'];
    $quantidade = $linha['quantity']
    // $adicionar = '<a href="carrinho.php?id='.$linha['ID'].'"title="'.$linha['ID'].'">
    //  Adicionar </a>'
?>
<div id="espaço">  
    <!-- Categorias principais -->
    <div id="baixo">
        <div class="prodColuna">
            <table width="200" height="300" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" scope="col" height="39"><?php echo $nome ?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="35" colspan="2"><?php echo $preco ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="184" colspan="2"><?php echo $modelo ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="39"><?php echo $categoria ?></td>
                    <td width="145" height="30"><?php echo $id ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It must be some tag that i didnt close.

Comment: I forgot my css code: http://pastebin.com/DtVkJ68V

Comment: Get some tools to help: Firebug can help reveal where an element may not be closed as you suspect, and view source in Firefox, and it will indicate red tags (for example, the closing body tag) if there is invalid markup.  Finally, you can view source and copy-paste it into a good text editor such as EditPad Pro, and the syntax highlighting will make it very quick to see where your broken tags are

Comment: @user2687822 You're better off pasting the source code so we can see the rendered HTML. It's most likely a HTML issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're opening 2 divs in a `while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))` loop, and not closing them:

```
<div id="espaço">  
<!-- Categorias principais -->
<div id="baixo">
```

You're closing them outside of the loop, but if there are more than 1 of each (for example loop iterate 3 times), 2 `</div>` tags outside of the loop won't close all of 6 opened div tags. You should either open your

```
<div id="espaço">  
<!-- Categorias principais -->
<div id="baixo">
```

ABOVE the loop, or close them INSIDE the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing two close div tag

```
//Your while loop start
<div id="espaço">  
  <div id="baixo">
     ...
  //Your code - While loop is closed
  </div>
</div>
//You must close while loop here not above.
```

Please check your code:

```
<?php include('cms/conectar.php');
?>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<style>
.prodColuna { text-align:center; width:300px; float:left; height:100%  }
</style>


<?php
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `livros-desporto` ");

 if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
    $consulta = mysql_query("
        SELECT * FROM `livros-desporto` where name like '%".$_POST['buscar']."%'
    ");
}

while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    $id = $linha['ID'];
    $modelo = $linha['Model'];
    $nome = $linha['Name'];
    $categoria = $linha['Category'];
    $imagem = $linha['Image'];
    $manufactura = $linha['Manufacturer'];
    $preco = $linha['Price'];
    $quantidade = $linha['quantity']
    // $adicionar = '<a href="carrinho.php?id='.$linha['ID'].'"title="'.$linha['ID'].'">
    //  Adicionar </a>'
?>
<div id="espaço">  
    <!-- Categorias principais -->
    <div id="baixo">
        <div class="prodColuna">
            <table width="200" height="300" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2" scope="col" height="39"><?php echo $nome ?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="35" colspan="2"><?php echo $preco ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="184" colspan="2"><?php echo $modelo ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="39"><?php echo $categoria ?></td>
                    <td width="145" height="30"><?php echo $id ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```